# Gradle precompiled script plugin : accessing another precompiled script plugin extension

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

In my buildSrc, I have one precompiled script plugin used to configure the feature name of my module (in a multi module project) like so :

`buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myFeature.gradle.kts`:

```
interface MyFeaturePluginExtension {
    val name: Property<String>
}

val extension = extension.create<MyFeaturePluginExtension>("myFeature")
extension.name.convention(project.name.substringBefore("-"))
```

So in my modules, I can override the default name like so.

`awesomeFeature/build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `my-feature`
}

myFeature {
    name.set("awesome-feature")
}
```

I would like to use this name in another precompiled script plugin but can't find how.

I tried this :

`buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/baseDeps.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("my-feature")
}

val featureName = the<MyFeaturePluginExtension>().name.get()

dependencies {
   "implementation"(project(":$featureName-domain"))
}
```

I get the following error :
`Unresolved reference: MyFeaturePluginExtension`